# how to accept value as int from QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have set 3 QLineEdits that are supposed to have float variable or int

```
  self.sfEdt=QtGui.QLineEdit()
  self.efEdt=QtGui.QLineEdit()
  self.bfEdt=QtGui.QLineEdit()
```

and even set the validators

```
      self.sfEdt.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator())
      self.efEdt.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator())
      self.byfrEdt.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator())
```

but when i check the value type it is QString, how should get the value as int or float ?

because the value that is displayed in these QLineEdit is loaded float converted to to string and if i do not convert it to String it is by Default QString, either their should be a way value entered or loaded into QLineEdit can stay float...

Comment: Don't really understand your question, but what's wrong with `int(self.sfEdt.text())`?

Comment: this should work but instead of user entering if the float value is fed to QLineEdit it becomes double and then converting it to int gives error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.0'